# Laravel4.2 Class 'Krucas\Notification\NotificationServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel

My make up a project by laravel4.2;
(1)first,I install the "edvinaskrucas/notification"
in my composer.json in the require-line like this:

```
     "require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "cartalyst/sentry":"2.1.4",
    "fzaninotto/faker":"1.5.*@dev",
    "edvinaskrucas/notification": "4.0.0"
},
```

(2)second, I join two lines codes  into my laravel config file config/app.php  below each last line like this :

```
'providers' => array(

    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Session\CommandsServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Database\MigrationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Remote\RemoteServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\ReminderServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Database\SeedServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Workbench\WorkbenchServiceProvider',
    'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider',
    'Cartalyst\Sentry\SentryServiceProvider',  
    'Krucas\Notification\NotificationServiceProvider'  ***--this new join in***
),

'aliases' => array(

    'App'               => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',
    'Artisan'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan',
    'Auth'              => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth',
    'Blade'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade',
    'Cache'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache',
    'ClassLoader'       => 'Illuminate\Support\ClassLoader',
    'Config'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config',
    'Controller'        => 'Illuminate\Routing\Controller',
    'Cookie'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie',
    'Crypt'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt',
    'DB'                => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB',
    'Eloquent'          => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model',
    'Event'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event',
    'File'              => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\File',
    'Form'              => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Form',
    'Hash'              => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash',
    'HTML'              => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\HTML',
    'Input'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input',
    'Lang'              => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang',
    'Log'               => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log',
    'Mail'              => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail',
    'Paginator'         => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Paginator',
    'Password'          => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password',
    'Queue'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue',
    'Redirect'          => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect',
    'Redis'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis',
    'Request'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request',
    'Response'          => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response',
    'Route'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route',
    'Schema'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema',
    'Seeder'            => 'Illuminate\Database\Seeder',
    'Session'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session',
    'SoftDeletingTrait' => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait',
    'SSH'               => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\SSH',
    'Str'               => 'Illuminate\Support\Str',
    'URL'               => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL',
    'Validator'         => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator',
    'View'              => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\View',
    'Sentry'            => 'Cartalyst\Sentry\Facades\Laravel\Sentry',
    'Notification'      => 'Krucas\Notification\Facades\Notification'   ***-->and this new***
),
```

(3) when i refresh the firefox after "dump-autoload the composer.json", then comes my question:

it says :

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR) 
>   Class 'Krucas\Notification\NotificationServiceProvider' not found!

What can I do to resolve this problem? Hope someone who sees this can help me.

Comment: Did you run `composer update`?

Comment: thank you so much,after i fun composer update. It works!well done!Amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To actually install a package you have to run `composer update` after adding it to `composer.json`.

`composer update` will detect the package added to `composer.json` and download the source.

Comment: I just doubt what is the difference between "composer update" and "composer dump-autoload"?

Comment: `composer update` will install a package by downloading it into the vendor folder. `composer dump-autoload` re-generates the autoload files. Those files are used to load all the classes in memory when the application runs. [here's an article](http://www.developed.be/2014/08/29/composer-dump-autoload-laravel/) on the topic

Answer (score 0):

Comment those two "joins" and do a composer dump-autoload and after uncomment those lines

Comment: i see. i should use "composer update" instead of "composer dump-autoload", though i still doubt with these two command.